# xcode 6, ios 8, object-C++

Tags: ios, xcode

I create a new app project(not library or framework), and then I set "compile source as" as object-C++.But when I compile the source, it shows “build failed”.

The error is :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_UIApplicationMain", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

but what makes me confused  is that :
if it is a framework project,it compiles well.
Could you lend me a hand !

Comment: Didn't you forget to rename implementation files to .mm extensions?

Comment: Why object-c++ and not just objective-c?

Comment: Renaming .m to .mm did not help!

Comment: I wanna use template in C++

Answer (score 18):

Your app's missing symbols from UIKit. You need to link your app to UIKit:

- Select the project in the project navigator (cmd+1, top left in left panel)
- Select the target (i.e. your app) under TARGETS
- Click "Build Phases" tab
- Click the "Link Binary with Libraries" disclosure triangle, unless the table is already visible
- Click the '+' at the bottom of the table
- Double click UIKit.framework to add it to your link stage

Once that is completed, there may be new link issues which are discovered.

Comment: @justin Dude you saved me from banging my head against the wall :D Thanks man ;)